# Is there a concurrent circular linked queue collection in java?

Tags: java, collections

I need to fetch data from the queue in a round-robin concurrent way. I am looking for a collection that implements such behavior. After some digging, I cannot find one. How would I implement one? 
I was looking at the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, but I am not sure how to make it circular. I need this collection to be highly performant.

I'm guessing I can do it with `ConcurrentLinkedDeque`. By using an iterator, I should be able to iterate all the way to the end, and once the end is reached I can re-create my iterator and go from the beginning.

=============================UPDATE===========================

Elements will be added to such collection by several threads during the initialization phase. Concurrent collection's state will be properly visible to the consumer threads that will be consuming one item at a time from it. Once the application is in a running state, elements won't be added to the collection. Only iteration and consumption of one element at a time by each thread in a cyclic fashion.

Comment: Why does it have to be circular?

Comment: That's a requirement

Comment: What you are describing is not a queue.   And since it isn't, you need to explain the required behavior more clearly.  Are new elements added?  Are old elements removed?  If elements are added / removed, how does this affect the process of round-robin fetching?

Comment: Also, I suspect that there may be some "premature optimization" going on here.  Do you have any hard evidence that the collection needs to be highly performant / that there is likely to be contention over the collection?

Comment: @StephenC see my update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your revised question, this is what I would recommend:

For the initializing phase, use a concurrent `Queue` or `Deque` to accumulate the elements.   Any implementation will do.

Once that phase is complete, create an instance of the following `RoundRobin` class from the queue object, and use its `get` method to the cycle through its elements.

```
public class RoundRobin <E> {
    private final AtomicInteger next = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private final E[] elements;

    public RoundRobin(Collection<E> queue, Class<E> clazz) {
        this.elements = queue.toArray(Array.newInstance(clazz, 0));
    }

    public E get() {
        return elements[next.getAndIncrement() % elements.length];
    }
}
```

The `RoundRobin` class is thread-safe and `get` is concurrent.

If the `elements` collection is mutated while you are constructing the `RoundRobin`, then the resulting `RoundRobin` state *may not* be the same as the final state of `queue`.  From my reading of your stated requirements, that is OK.

Comment: Ok, but when an element actually gets added to the queue, I'd have to re-create the RoundRobin. I know, I stated that there is the init phase, during which most elements will be added, but there could be some that won't be added during the init phase. 
It just makes me think if `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is gonna be a better fit. And what do you think of proposed `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` impl?

Comment: I designed `RoundRobin` on the assumption that it only needed to be created once.   I have no comment on your proposal.  The best approach will depend on the requirements, and they keep changing.

Comment: You are right, your answer is based on requirements stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing fits with a linked list, not a queue or deque. With a linked list, you could point the "next" node from the last element to point at the first. However, looking at [Javadoc for LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), there is no way to change where the last element points.

Note that if there was a way, you could create a synchronized view of that data structure by call [Collections.synchronizedList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) like this:

```
List<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<>());
```

For standard Java API, I don't think you can accomplish what you are trying to do. An option would be to implement your own data structure that extends `List` and allows you to alter where each node points so that you can make circular. Then use `Collections.synchronizedList()` to create a thread-safe view of it.

Note that Javadoc for `Collections.synchronizedList()` says: *"It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it"* and includes this example:

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
    ...
synchronized (list) {
    Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
    while (i.hasNext())
        foo(i.next());
}
```

Comment: I know none of that fits, but ConcurrentLinkedDeque seems like a winner.
Synchronized collections are slow in comparison to concurrent classes. Concurrent classes are more performant as they do less blocking.

Comment: Concurrent classes are more performant, but does your use case actually require the additional performance? It may. Using `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` with repeated iterators can work, but there's a cost to creating a new iterator each time – whatever your performance criteria is, you'll want to factor that in. I don't think there are any great options that meet all of the requirements you're looking for, so you'll need to make whatever trade offs fit best. One other thought: it's best to get a correct, working version, then profile and speed it up later if you need it to be faster.